# How to do Do a redirect in buildForm()?

Tags: forms, redirection

I send a link to a URL by email. This page is created with a controller which contains a form (FormAPI). I pass a token as a parameter to secure access to this form. So I check if this token exists and I display the form. Everything works correctly.

If the token does not exist, I would like to redirect in the buildform to a custom route. But I can not.

I tried different things like this but it doesn't seem to work in the buid form.

```
 public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $token = null): array {

        $nodes = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
            ->getStorage('node')
            ->loadByProperties([
                'field_token' => $token,
            ]);

        // Checks if the node array is not empty.
        if (!empty($nodes)) {
            $node = reset($nodes);
            $nid = $node->id();
        } else {
            // Here, I want to redirect to custom route
            dump('ko');

            //return new RedirectResponse(Url::fromRoute('my_custom_route')->toString());
            //$form_state->setRedirect('my_custom_route');

            //return $this->redirect('my_custom_route');
            // return $form_state->setRedirect('('my_custom_route')');
        }
}
```

Do you know how I can do it? Otherwise, rather than using a controller and a custom route, I will generate a different form depending on the condition (a form without fields but with custom markup). But I prefer a controller.

I know how to redirect in `submitForm()` or in a controller. Here, the redirect is in `buildForm()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use RedirectResponse, e.g.

```
use Drupal\Core\Url;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

$response = new RedirectResponse(URL::fromRoute('my_custom_route')->toString());
$response->send();
```

Answer (score 3):

If the form is in a route via the `_form` key you can return the redirect the same as in a controller, the core form controller is able to pass the response to the Drupal kernel. If the form is in a custom controller you have to pass it from the form to the controller and return it.

BTW the response send method is a low-level method not suitable for a
Symfony app like Drupal. The Symfony kernel has to return a response and not send one.